# Suggest another method of achieving this "word stack" which resolves the known issues my method is a victim of

Tags: php, javascript, css, overflow

I am trying to transform a set of two radio buttons in a stack of two labels, one blue and on gray representing, respectively, the selected radio and the unselected one. Clicking on this stack will change which of the labels is blue (and which of the radio buttons is checked). It works well but it breaks down in an ugly manner when the two labels aren't of the same width. The best way to see what I mean is to try the test page I made out on your own server or to navigate [here](http://www.groupes.polymtl.ca/echanges/wordStacks.php) to see the page in action.

The comments in the source code and actual content explain pretty much what I am aiming for and what the problems are. Also, this is an attempt at accessibility and graceful degradation, so any remarks concerning those issues are most welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>word stacks</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <style type="text/css">

            .stackContainer
            {
                line-height: 2em;   /* Prevents the stackBottom from overlaping the second line of text found in the stack container, should there be a second line. */
            }

            .stack
            {
                position: relative; /* Needed to give the absolutely positionned stackBottom a positionned reference. */
            }

            .stackTop
            {
                vertical-align: .5em;   /* Raise the stackTop half a line */
            }

            .stackBottom
            {
                background: transparent;    /* Needed so the background doesn't cover the stackTop nor the line below, if any. */
                position: absolute; /* Positionned absolutely in reference to the stack */
                left: 0;    /* Bring the stackBottom directly under the stackTop */
                top: 0; /* For some reason, this is needed to bring the stackBottom under the stackTop. */
            }

            /* The following is extra */
            .stackSelected  /* Represents the chosen  value */
            {
                color: #009;
            }

            .stackUnselected    /* Represents the other option */
            {
                color: #777;
            }

            .stack
            {
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            p
            {
                margin: 3em;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
            function createWordStack($name, $value1, $value2)
            {
                // Set default values (by default, $value1 is checked and not $value2)
                $firstChecked = "checked=\"checked\" ";
                $secondChecked = "";
                if(isset($_POST[$name]))    // One value was chosen
                {
                    if($_POST[$name] == $value2)    // Not default value
                    {
                        $firstChecked = "";
                        $secondChecked = "checked=\"checked\" ";
                    }
                    // else fall back to default value
                }
                // else fall back to default value
                // Write out the html
                echo("<span class=\"stack\">
                        <label for=\"" . $name . "\">
                            <input type=\"radio\" name=\"" . $name . "\" value=\"" . $value1 . "\" " . $firstChecked . "/>" . $value1 . "
                        </label>
                        <label for=\"" . $name . "\">
                            <input type=\"radio\" name=\"" . $name . "\" value=\"" . $value2 . "\" " . $secondChecked . "/>" . $value2 . "
                        </label>
                    </span>");
            }
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // It is recommended to use this function only if stacks have been created with the php function createStack and if these stacks are contained in an element of class stackContainer
            function makeStacks()
            {
                var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");  // Find all forms
                var nb_forms = forms.length;
                for(var i = 0; i < nb_forms; ++i)
                {
                    if(forms[i].className.indexOf("stackContainer") != -1)  // If it's a stackContainer
                    {
                        var spans = forms[i].getElementsByTagName("span");  // Find all spans
                        var nb_spans = spans.length;
                        for(var j = 0; j < nb_spans; ++j)
                        {
                            if(spans[j].className.indexOf("stack") != -1)   // If it's a stack
                            {
                                var labels = spans[j].getElementsByTagName("label");    // Find all labels
                                var nb_labels = labels.length;
                                if(nb_labels == 2)  // Only works with two labels!
                                {
                                    labels[0].className += " stackTop";
                                    labels[1].className += " stackBottom";
                                    for(var k = 0; k < nb_labels; ++k)
                                    {
                                        var inputs = labels[k].getElementsByTagName("input");   // Find all inputs
                                        var nb_inputs = inputs.length;
                                        if(nb_inputs == 1 && inputs[0].type == "radio") // Only works with one radio button per label!
                                        {
                                            inputs[0].style.display = "none";   // Hide radio button
                                            labels[k].className += (inputs[0].checked)?" stackSelected":" stackUnselected";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                // add onclick listener to invert which radio button is checked and invert which label appears on top
                                spans[j].onclick = function()
                                {
                                    var labels = this.getElementsByTagName("label");    // Find all labels
                                    // We already know that there are only two labels, from earlier!
                                    for(var l = 0; l < 2; ++l)
                                    {
                                        // Invert className from stackTop to stackBottom (or vice-versa)
                                        if(labels[l].className.match(/stackSelected/))
                                        {
                                            labels[l].className = labels[l].className.replace(/stackSelected/, "stackUnselected");
                                        }
                                        else if(labels[l].className.match(/stackUnselected/))
                                        {
                                            labels[l].className = labels[l].className.replace(/stackUnselected/, "stackSelected");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // Change which of the radios is checked
                                    var inputs = labels[0].getElementsByTagName("input");   // Find all inputs from first label
                                    // We already know that there is a single label and that it is a radio, from earlier!
                                    if(!inputs[0].checked)  // If this one is not checked, check it to change which of the radios is checked
                                    {
                                        inputs[0].checked = true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var inputs = labels[1].getElementsByTagName("input");   // Find all inputs from second label
                                        // We already know that there is a single label and that it is a radio, from earlier!
                                        if(!inputs[0].checked)  // If this one is not checked, check it to change which of the radios is checked
                                        {
                                            inputs[0].checked = true;
                                        }
                                        // else there is something wrong as none of the radios are checked!
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            window.onload = makeStacks;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Word stacks</h1>

        <h2>How it works</h2>
        <ol>
            <li>PHP transforms<br />
                <code>&lt;?php createWordStack("name","one","two"); ?&gt</code><br />
                into<br />
                <code>
                    <pre>
&lt;span class="stack"&gt;
    &lt;label for="name"&gt;
        &lt;input type="radio" name="name" value="one" /&gt;one
    &lt;/label&gt;

    &lt;label for="name"&gt;
        &lt;input type="radio" name="name" value="two" checked="checked" /&gt;two
    &lt;/label&gt;
&lt;/span&gt;
                    </pre>
                </code>
            </li>
            <li>
                javascript hides the radio buttons, applies class declarations to the labels and adds an onclick event listener to the<br />
                <code>
                    &lt;span class="stack"&gt;
                </code>
            </li>
        </ol>

        <h2 id="example">Example</h2>
        <form action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "#example"); ?>" class="stackContainer" method="post">
            <p>Choose between <?php createWordStack("name","one","two"); ?> options.</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Test that the radio buttons hidden behind this still work" />
        </form>
        <h3>print_r($_POST)</h3>
        <pre>
            <?php print_r($_POST); ?>
        </pre>

        <form class="stackContainer">
            <h2>Known issues</h2>
            <p>
                This technique
                <?php createWordStack("no_matter","absolutely does not","does"); ?>
                look good with two different sizes of `words`,
                <?php createWordStack("no_matter2","no matter","although this depends"); ?>
                in which order they appear. If looks better when the longer word is above the other though. Plus, the way it breaks makes it unreadable when the longer word is on the bottom if the remainder of the text needs to span many lines.
            </p>
            <p>
                Another problem is when the bottom word
                <?php createWordStack("no_matter3","is","isn't"); ?>
                longer than the top word but actually consists of a single word. It cannot wrap and therefore interferes with the following text.
            </p>

            <p>
                <?php createWordStack("no_matter4","It really becomes unusable and quite ugly if the top word happens to wrap and span over two or more lines. Of course, the first know issue shown above is enough to understand that THIS known issue doesn't mean a thing if it is the bottom that is too long as it will span over many lines no matter what since it is limited by the width of the shorter word above..","It still works"); ?>
                .. and so, all in all, it is better to avoid long words altogether.
            </p>
            <p>
                Now, just to illustrate what I am saying above.. 
                <?php createWordStack("no_matter5","Look at this shit!","It really becomes unusable and quite ugly if the top word happens to wrap and span over two or more lines. Of course, the first know issue shown above is enough to understand that THIS known issue doesn't mean a thing if it is the bottom that is too long as it will span over many lines no matter what since it is limited by the width of the shorter word above.."); ?>
                .. and so, all in all, it is better to avoid long words altogether.
            </p>
            <h2>Notes</h2>
            <p>
                At least, the next paragraph
                <?php createWordStack("no_matter6","isn't","is"); ?>
                pushed down too far.
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php createWordStack("no_matter7","It works","It doesn't work"); ?>
                when I put the stackBottom BEFORE the stackTop, so I could also call them stackChosen and stackAlternate and just change the className in order to choose one or the other. This is what the javascript used to do when you click on the stack: if the label is of class stackTop, it changes it to stackBottom, and vice-versa. Now, only the colour is changed..
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the question is: How would I go about resolving the known issues explained in the test page?
I'm sorry, I know this is no way of asking a question, but I just don't know how else to phrase it. I did put much effort in making this test page as clear as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The missing Doctype **IS** an issue. There's no point at comparing a test page in quirks mode and a real one in Standard mode :/

Comment: Understood, I've added the doctype in and the meta type defining the charset. Anything else? Oh, and by the way, these didn't change anything.

Comment: I don't think you're likely to find many people willing to read through a script this long without even knowing what they're looking for. Rather than say "Rrun my script and tell me how to fix it", I suggest listing what's wrong and asking for solutions (or creating separate questions for separate problems).

Comment: You're right, of course, but I'm finding it difficult to explain the problem to someone who doesn't see it. The easiest way is to add the page to your own server and open it up. In the page, I give an explanation of how it works, I show how it looks like when it works well and I show how it looks like when it breaks. It's really not that long to check, you just need to add it to your www foler and open it up.. However, I will try explaining the problems in the actual question. Thanks

Comment: Just my two cents: don't do this. You shouldn't try to make your own user interface with elements that jump to another position when you click on them. Those elements really should stay on the same place. It reminds me of http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PLTZxLNTUk#t=0m27s

Comment: I like to think my "user interface" isn't as bad as that one on youtube. Nor are the consequences as dramatic. But maybe I should simply swap the colours and leave the words where they are. Thanks for the comment, I will make the change and update the post.

Comment: Colour swapping sounds already a bit better, but choose the right ones. I know a lot of DVD menus with two options, e.g. one blue, one yellow, without a sign of what colour represents the ‘active’ option. Also be aware of colourblind people.

Comment: good point, I'll stick with the same colour scheme I maintain throughout the website

Comment: In that case: why not just stick to ordinary radio buttons? Nowadays everyone recognizes them as such, while it's very likely that visitors of your site will have to think about the meaning of those coloured texts.

Comment: Yes, but this method saves so much space on the screen. It's also a great deal prettier if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using position absolute for your stack bottom broke everything (browser couldn't take the stack bottom width into account), here is an alternative uses inline-bock instead

Replace your .stack, .stackTop and .stackBottom definition by those:

```
.stack{
  display: inline-block; /* prevent the block options to induce line breaks in your text */
  line-height: 1; /* Have the 2 options verticaly close to each other */
  position: relative; /* Moves the lines to be in between*/
  top: 0.5em;
  white-space: nowrap; /* prevent line breaks */
}

.stackTop,
.stackBottom{
  display: block; /* Stack the options on top of each other */
}
```

Comment: Very nice. It seems to work on Firefox and Epiphany. Do you have any other browsers at hand which you could test this on?

Comment: Works on webkit based browsers (safari + chrome), should work with fairly recent versions of IE

Comment: I've got news from someone else that it indeed works with MSIE7. If anyone could test Opera, this would pass with flying colours! Are you worried about the older versions of IE?

Comment: I know that IE6 doesn't support inline-block, but don't worry about opera, this will work on it. While not my favorite, it's still a great browser